# laravel count user attendances by month

Tags: laravel

```
@foreach($users as $user)
{{$user->name }}
@foreach($user->attendances as $attend)
@if( $attend->date->format('F') === $today->format('F')  )
{{ $user->attendances->count() }}
@endif 
@endforeach
@endforeach
```

The Answer => Total count not Month

Comment: What's the question exactly?

Comment: i want count attendance by month

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple solution, eloquent has whereDate and whereMonth methods,

```
{{ $user->attendances()->whereMonth('created_at',\Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('m') )->count() }}
```

Hope It will help

Comment: you want count of attendance for current month??

Comment: `{{ $user->attendances()->whereMonth('date',$today->toDateString())->count() }}`

Comment: and column name is date?? you can change column date to created_at

Comment: {{ $user->attendances()->whereMonth('created_at',$today->toDateString())->count() }}

Comment: what is the created at value for that record??

Comment: record = absent

Comment: {{ $user->attendances()->whereMonth('created_at',\Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('m') )->count() }}